# Getting direction of object moved by the physics engine

Tags: objective-c, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, skphysicsworld

i am using spritekit to learn about physics behaviour in games, when a sprite node ball bounces off a surface, the physics engine will automatically calculate its new direction.

how do i get this new direction in code?

i am using swift, xcode spritekit. but object c spritekit (cocos2d) is fine too

(the aim is to get a fire trail behind the bouncing ball, but i dont know how to rotate the particle emitter based on ball's vector of movement. the emitter is currently added as a child of the ball node)

Comment: Make use of the zRotation property.

Comment: @Zemoon you sir are a genius and a scholar and a gentleman

Comment: What's the problem with keeping the emitter as a child of the ball node?

Comment: the problem is, the physics engine doesn't rotate the ball if we apply only a vector to move it, so the emitter doesn't change its emission angle

Comment: what we get is the ball and its child nodes moving in the direction applied by the vector, and then when the ball bounces off one of the physics node bodies in the scene, the vector changes direction, but the ball still faces the same direction (same problem again)

Comment: the original solution provided by Jean-Baptiste Yunès to use atan2(dy/dx) was correct and useful (to me anyway)

Comment: Have you set ball.physicsBody.allowsRotation to TRUE?

Comment: to make a particle emitter trail behind a node use `emitter.targetNode=ballNode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the "direction" you should read the `velocity` property of the `physicsBody` of your node.

To rotate your particle emitter, you should modify the `zRotation` property of the node.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the most best idea for getting a rotation of a node is getting `eulerAngles`. But since it showed radians, I converted to degrees. This is the code that I got when getting the rotation of a camera Node

```
print(round(GLKMathRadiansToDegrees(Float(gameController.camera.eulerAngles.z))))
```

Hope This helps